# Why the bash can't find the file?

Tags: 18.04, bash

I upgrade my virtual machine from ubuntu 10 to ubuntu 18. After the upgrade I can't open executables. What I'm doing wrong?

```
server@vm-server:~$ cd login/
server@vm-server:~/login$ ls -l
total 30520
drwxrwxr-x 2 server server     4096 Apr 19 14:12 anti
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server  9321752 Apr 19 14:12 guard
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      250 Apr 19 14:12 guard_user.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      251 Apr 19 14:12 guard_user.ini~
drwxrwxr-x 2 server server     4096 Apr 19 14:12 log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      365 Apr 19 14:12 login_engine.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server 21861975 Apr 19 14:12 login_server
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server    16722 Apr 19 14:12 login_server.bcfg
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      665 Apr 19 14:12 login_user.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      660 Apr 19 14:12 login_user.ini~
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server       94 Apr 19 14:12 run_new.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      161 Apr 19 14:12 run.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 server server      113 Apr 19 14:12 run.sh~
server@vm-server:~/login$ ./login_server
-bash: ./login_server: No such file or directory
server@vm-server:~/login$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
server@vm-server:~/login$
```

additional info:
I update by copy my files on my real machine, erase everything on the virtual, instal ubuntu server 18.04 and copy my files back.

```
server@vm-server:~/login$ uname -m
x86_64
server@vm-server:~/login$ file ./login_server
./login_server: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, with debug_info, not stripped
server@vm-server:~/login$ ldd ./login_server
        not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Upgraded how, exactly? What are the outputs of `uname -m`, `file ./login_server`, and `ldd ./login_server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you installed a 64 bit desktop this time, and your old executables are 32 bit.  You need to install the 32 bit libraries, start with libc6-i386, then you will have a ldd which will list the other needed 32 bit libraries instead of claiming wrongly "not a dynamic executable".

Ubuntu does come with enough ELF utilities to allow the ldd script to produce a reasonable output when a specific architecture loader is not present. [Bug 1616609](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1616609) addresses his issue, join it and maybe it will be fixed some day.

Comment: In particular, the "not a dynamic executable" should go away once you install `libc6-i386` (which provides the 32-bit dynamic loader `/lib32/ld-linux.so.2`)